# Obtain bundle version at compile time in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, bundle

In Cocoa you can use `NSBundle` to obtain the current bundle version number in your code, see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015304/refer-to-build-number-or-version-number-in-code) question.

How can you do the same thing at compile time? For example, if you want to make a compile time assertion based on the bundle version.

Maybe there is a predefined macro for that?

Comment: assertion to do what ?

Comment: Something weird, I have to admit... some dirty work around that I may or may not consider doing and that has to do with a very odd cross-platform portability issue. I won't go into details, but I would be interested to know if this should be generally possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly have a macro that will expand to values from Info.plist. What you can do is the other way around: add a predefined setting that holds the bundle version, and reference it in Info.plist; you'll also have it available in your code.